# Notificação Android

Tags: android, android-notification

Tenho um projeto bem simples para teste que no evento ***onCreate*** da tela 1 envia uma notificação, que ao clicar abre a tela 2.

Propositalmente, eu clico de forma rápida na notificação para abrir a nova tela (afim de testes) fazendo um espécie de "Stress" para simular algum tipo de erro.

O problema é que hora abre normalmente e outras vezes fica uma tela branca.

Por que isso ocorre?

Testei em 3 aparelhos:

- Samsung CORE 2 - NÃO FUNCIONOU TODAS AS VEZES.
- Samsung Galaxy s3 mini - FUNCIONOU TODAS AS VEZES.
- Samsung Galaxy s duos - DEU PROBLEMA POUCAS VEZES

Isso tem a ver com a memória RAM, processador? Ou meu código está executando algo em ordem errada?

```
public void sendNotification() {

    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    Intent it = new Intent(this, NovaTela.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NovaTela.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(it);
    PendingIntent pit = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pit)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Teste Notificação")
                    .setContentText("teste");

    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Amigo, faça um teste: adicione a flag ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK para abrir  a NovaTela: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: Já tentei e continua o mesmo problema....

Comment: Exibe algum erro no LogCat?

Comment: Nenhum, por isso gostaria de entender por que as vezes aparece a tela branca onde consigo clicar nos elementos ao fundo porém não consigo visualizar nada, sendo que em alguns dispositivos funcionam normalmente...

Answer (score 4):

O porque aparece, hora sim, hora não, é meio complicado! As vezes pode ser a versão do Sistema, entre outras. 
Tente da seguinte forma :

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());

final Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NovaTela.class);

i.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );

builder.setTicker("Ticker text. . . ");
builder.setContentTitle(" Content title text....");
builder.setContentText("Description text....");
builder .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);

final PendingIntent open = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder.setContentIntent(open);
notificationManager.notify(12345, builder.build());
```

Comment: Com isso eu posso adicionar um AddParentStack sem ter problemas?

Comment: Ao invés de AddParentStack, vc adiciona um intent:  Intent it = new Intent(this, NovaTela.class);

Comment: Eu digo pois se eu tiver que abrir essa notificação sem abrir a aplicação e ao pressionar o botão voltar, quiser voltar para tela 1.

Comment: perdão, não entendi... O Serviço mandou a Notificação, eu clico e abro a NovaTela,  se eu clicar em Voltar, ele deve abrir a Tela Inicial da aplicação?

Comment: Isso! Exatamente.

Comment: Nesse caso teria problema em usar o addParentStack?

Comment: Acredito que não haja problema! Vou pesquisar certinho, mas acho que isto pode ser declarado no Manifest.  Na declaração da NovaTela, diz que ela é uma Tela interna da principal.

Comment: Sim isso é tranquilo de fazer, gostaria de saber se não voltará a ter o problema da tela branca....

Comment: Só mais uma coisa...

Comment: Se eu estou já na tela 2 e clico na notificação é possível fazer com que ela crie novamente? Eu quero isso.

Comment: Sem que preserve entende?